# undefined method `number' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having problems display an attribute in a belongs_to relationship. Lease belongs_to Unit. Unit has a column "number" in the db. When I try to display this attribute on the lease show page, it gives me an error of undefined method `number' for nil:NilClass. I feel like I'm doing something stupid and over looking it.

lease.rb

```
belongs_to :unit
```

unit.rb

```
has_many :leases
```

leases_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @lease = Lease.find(params[:id])
  end
```

views/leases/show.html.erb

```
<%= @lease.unit.number %>
```

If I change my show page code to @lease.unit_id it will show the id of the unit. Here is a pic of my data base showing the Unit_id.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model may have unit_id attribute, but how about `units` that does not have that record with `id = 1` have You checked?

Quick (dirty) fix:

```
<%= @lease.unit.number unless @lease.unit.nil? %>
```

Comment: This clears the error, but doesn't display anything.

Comment: @DhatchXIX cuz I said, check units table if it has unit with id

Comment: I forgot I messed with my db testing other stuff and forgot to change it all back. I appreciate you walking me through that I knew it was something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

you have to validate the Unit ID's presence on Lease model

```
validates :unit, presence: true
```

so your Lease model wouldn't be saved to database unless you've set the unit_id to Lease instance

now you may delete your existing Unit records from database, and start again.

you may need to add more integrity of each data, please read [this](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/referential-integrity-with-foreign-keys)

---

### update

ok how about if "DBAs deleting records under some circumstancies" ?

you can delegate to Unit#number to Lease instance

```
delegate :number, to: :unit, prefix: true
```

now you can access the lease.unit.number even when the unit_id is nil, you can access it using `lease.unit_number`

Comment: That's right, but how about situations when DBAs deleting records under some circumstancies? Any app must be stable to any kinds of failures, even if some record does not exist. (;

Comment: About deleting data: it's useful practice to not to delete data, but set `deleted` flag in table, some kind of softDelete feature. Human behavior is unpredictable, so I always use `softDelete` technique, and have my garbage collector tasks that run once a day and purge deleted records that has `deleted=1` month ago.

Comment: please check my updated answer above, I told him to delete the data because I assumed that he is on development environment

Comment: I know what You're trying to say, but it's not the answer of question, it's solution to prevent failure situations. but it's nice solution, upvote was by me (;

Comment: ok thanks, but regarding 'deleted' flag, that is also out of scope of this question, and not required for each application, so it's depending on app requirement, don't add any complex thing until you need it -> http://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html

Comment: That's nice that You're sharing the ideas of YAGNI. That means You're productive, and don't write unnecessary things. About deleted flag, yes it's out of scope of question, but in comments I can talk about everything. (;